# How to get the numeric value as string value?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a column that the cells format is like this :
[image]

I have been being confused by this problem and I get this error "Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell".
How can I get the cell contains integer value "2040" as string where as it has been formatted as text in the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you're looking for is [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html). Excel itself will normally store numbers in the file as CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC, with appropriate formatting rules to make them render as you expect. If you want to turn the double value + format rules into a String, [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) will do that for you.

Your code can then look something like:

```
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();    

Row r = sheet.getRow(10);
Cell c = r.getCell(2, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
if (c == null) {
   // There's no value in this cell
} else {
   System.out.println("Cell K2 is " + fmt.formatCellValue(c));
}
```

Comment: it works fine for me.
thanks a lot for your reply and help ^^